# How to refresh features on a OL3 map automatically?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, wfs, openlayers, real-time

I am using OL3 and GeoServer and PostGIS as database. My database is connected to GeoServer and OL3 conected to GeoServer and reads the points in database as vector layer and shows on the map.

My data are changed every 5 seconds (position of points). I want to refresh the map automatically each 5 seconds to show the movement of the points.

Is there any way to do this?

EDIT: 
I am using WFS like this:

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.ServerVector({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),       
    loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
        var url = 'http://localhost:8000/geoserver/cite/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=cite:MyFeature&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application/json';
        $.ajax({
            url: url
        })
        .done(loadFeatures);
    }
});
```

I can use `window.setTimeout(function () { location.reload() }, 5000);` in the `loadFeatures` function to reload the page each 5 seconds. It is working but I am searching for a better way which refreshes the features and not the complete map.

Comment: How are you loading the data into the map. WFS, JSON, WKT? It is reasonably straightforward to make loops in Javascript on a timer, but more information would be useful.

Comment: @JohnBarça I provided information.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the window.setTimeout function is it reloads the whole page. If you want to reload only the layer data you can use this :

```
var timer = null;
var vectorSource = new ol.source.ServerVector({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),       
    loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
        if (timer != null) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            timer = null;
        }
        var url = 'http://localhost:8000/geoserver/cite/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=cite:MyFeature&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application/json';
        $.ajax({
            url: url
        })
        .done(loadFeatures);
    }
});
```

at the end of your loadFeatures function add:

```
if (timer == null) {
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        vectorSource.clear();
    }, 500);
}
```